# File created with blob does not support NON-ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob, single-page-application

First of all I have to say that  questions similar to this have been asked before, but the answers did not help.

- [Download BLOB content using specified charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925210/download-blob-content-using-specified-charset/18925211)
- [F-8 encoidng issue when exporting csv file , JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959487/utf-8-encoidng-issue-when-exporting-csv-file-javascript)

#### This is the code.

```js
ctrl.downloadFile = function (file) {
  var filename = file.filename.split("/"),
  name = (filename[filename.length - 1]);
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/download/' + name}, {responseType: "blob"}).then(
    function success(response) {
      var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers['content-type'] + ";text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF"}),
        url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL,
        fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
      var anchor = document.createElement('a');

      anchor.href = fileUrl;
      anchor.target = '_blank';
      anchor.download = name;
      anchor.style = "display: none";

      document.body.appendChild(anchor);
      anchor.click();

      setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(anchor);
      }, 100);
    }
  )
};
```

This is the html code that calls the `downloadFile()` function.

```html
<a  ng-click="$ctrl.downLoadFile(file)"  target='_blank'>{{file.filename}}</a>
```

The Downloaded file does not support German special characters(`Å`, `Ø`, `Ü` ). What to do that the file supports those characters?

**Update 1**: I have done this also. But it did not work either.

```
var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", response.data], 
                     {type: response.headers['content-type'] +
                      ";text/csv;charset=utf-8"})
```

**Update 2**: It works fine if  I use these characters(`Å`, `Ø`, `Ü` ) instead of the `response.data`.

```js
   var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", "Å Ø Ü" ], 
                         {type: response.headers['content-type'] +
                          ";text/csv;charset=utf-8"})
```

**Update 3**: This is a single page application. And Yes ,I have used  `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head section of the html page.

Comment: set the text encoding to something like UTF8, or whatever the input encoding formatting was.

Comment: Does not this  do that ? `{type: response.headers['content-type'] +  ";text/csv;charset=utf-8"}`

Comment: Try to Change Character Set to **ISO-8859-1** or **ISO/IEC 8859-15**.

Comment: The problem is, the text is displayed in the encoding the containing document is. So make sure your original html document is served with UTF-8 headers and meta tags so the browser uses UTF-8 .

Comment: @Tschallacka  character encoding is `utf-8`.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey It did not work.

Comment: @mahan Can you provide us with the headers your webpage is served, and did you use a meta charset=? in your header? Because if it doesn't work it seems that somewhere your document is not served/interpreted as UTF8

Comment: @Tschallacka. This is a single page application. Yes. I have used ` <meta charset="utf-8">`. I have checked the `response` in Chrome developer tool. There is no problem with it.

Comment: Where does `name` come from and why not just put the `download` attribute on the original anchor?

Comment: @musa `name` is a  variable defined in the function.I copied that portion of the code form an another `function`. Now, I have fixed the code.  Because I think it is easier and cleaner to write it in JavaScript rather than in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the whole `ctrl.downloadFile()` was unnecessary. Instead, I used a function to make the download link and then call it in `ng-href`.

```js
ctrl.urlForFile = function(file) {
  var split = file.filename.split("/");
  return '/download/' + file['xyz'] + "/" + split[split.length - 1];
};
```

```html
<a ng-href="{{$ctrl.urlForFile(file)}}" target='_blank'>{{file.filename}}</a>
```

If you do not need to make the download link dynamically, you should use the link directly in `ng-href`.

```html
<a ng-href="/download/xyz/dfdsf23423423" target='_blank'>{{file.filename}}</a>
```