# JavaScript: how to Download CSV file containing French text with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, blob, export-to-csv

I am trying to download CVS file using JavaScript. That CSV contains text in French language.
I am creating file using blob

```
    var blob = new Blob([ csv ], {
                type : 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
            });
    var csvUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

But when i open the csv file it shows the content in ANSII format due to which French characters are converted to some unknown characters.

But if i open the same file as text, the encoding is ok (UTF-8).

```
Example: Text I am trying to download "Opération"
Text Visible in Excel (.csv) ==> OpÃ©ration   <== With unknown characters
Text if opened in Notpad++ ==> Opération   <== Correct UTF-8
```

How can i open Download CSV file directly with UTF-8 encoding?
I don't want user to change anything in excel. I want some javascript format so that excel could recognize all my characters irrespective of its encoding. Is it possible to do something?

Comment: Sounds like an excel problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: Hi, Kaiido, I don't want user to change anything in excel. I want some javascript format so that excel could recognize all my characters irrespective of its encoding. Is it possible to suggest something?

Comment: Nope, this is an excel issue. For some reason they're not even capable of doing BOM identification on csv files. You are doing right in saving it as utf-8, MS is doing crap. Not your fault. Your users which needs these character sets will probably already be used to this anyway.

Comment: Ps: you could try to save as xls directly instead of csv : https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I met the same issue, and I found the following solution:

[similar problem and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002335/1608267)

The only thing to do is add the **"\ufeff"** at the beginning of your csv string:

```
var csv = "\ufeff"+CSV;
```